# interchange two numbers in a list

Tags: python

I have a list
`a=[1,2,3]`

If a condition is satisfied
`if condition == True`,
I want to change the order of the list to `a = [1,3,2]`

**What is the most efficient way of doing this in python?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.It's like swapping
`a[0], a[1]=a[1],a[0]`

For your specific case
`a[1], a[2]=a[2],a[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=[1,2,3]

if true:
    temp = a[1]
    a[1] = a[2]
    a[2] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_items=["a","b","c"]
print("Given List:", list_items)
list_items[0],list_items[2]=list_items[2],list_items[0]
print("Interchanged List:",list_items)
```

**output will be:**

```
Given List: ['a', 'b', 'c']
Interchanged List: ['c', 'b', 'a']
```